# Getting error while exceuting macro in mule

Tags: mule, teradata

I need to execute exec statement for teradata-macro in mulesoft.
 having below error..

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: [Teradata JDBC Driver] [TeraJDBC ] [Error 756] [SQLState HY000] Statement: Attempt to return a result set.

Please suggest...

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail about what this macro is trying to accomplish or perhaps the actual macro itself?

Comment: it is trying to get the records from tera db.
does mule support macro?

Comment: Probably not.. at least from what we see here. The log says that the Java code is expecting the statement to be some sort of update and so it doesn't expect the SQL statement to return a result set. Could you share the Mule configuration you used to execute the Macro?